React Native Expo with NativeWind messes up styles with Razorpay and Dark Mode
I have an application that works only in light mode using NativeWind. Whenever Razorpay is opened using my app and we come back to the app after payment, all the styles get messed up. This happens only when the Phone's theme is set to dark. I tried using forceDarkDisabled plugins and setting userInterface to light in app.json. None of the solutions seem to work. This issue happens only when I build a preview apk, in dev builds it works perfectly
